# How to deal with reactjs adding a surrounding div to my component?

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs adds a surrounding div to my component that breaks my layout. I want The text "Balance" and the amount to be on the same line.

```
<span>Balance:</span>  
<div id="Balance-react-component-7c517694-f02f-4cbb-aee1-08a98f7ea145">     
    <span data-reactroot="" class="balance">$3.00</span>
</div>
```

I know I could just have the component return the entire text, including the word Balance, but I don't want to do that. How do I stop react from outputting this div, or at least make it a span instead so it doesn't force a line break?

Comment: can you post your react code? I don't know a way of changing the container type. However I think this is actually something that should be tackled in CSS with either flexbox or inline-block/floats rather than changing a core way React works.

Comment: Yea this is an unusual situation. Can you post the components and the parent render that contains them?

Answer (score 1):

```
react_component("Balance",  
    :html_options => {:style => "display:inline-block"}
)
```

Was a case of RTFM, I found the solution is to use the `html_options` parameter to pass a style to the surrounding div. (Can also pass a class as well and style it that way.)